# Измерение расстояния пройденного за день gps android

Tags: android

Ребята, выручайте пожалуйста. Нужно определить сколько примерно в день проехал/прошел человек с помощью gps. Ну вообще у меня есть идеи как это сделать, но меня терзают смутные сомнения в этом вопросе. Например, можно пустить в сервис через AlarmManager, который будет определять координаты каждые там не знаю 10 сек, и постоянно искать расстояние от прошлой точке и забивать в базу. Второе, можно пусть сервис, в котором будет полностью реализован Location, там будет OnLocationChange и так далее. Но думается мне что второй способ не очень, потому, что значок gps будет раздражать юзера. А цель моего приложения - чтоб юзеру было хорошо и спокойно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без стабильного и практически постоянного доступа к GPS тут вряд ли обойтись. В любом случае вам придется узнавать как переместился пользователь за последнюю минуту/час/2 часа и т.д. Поэтому, действительно, нужно будет задействовать механизмы, связанные с временными интервалами( тот же AlarmManager ).

Вопрос тут в том, как же все-таки потреблять меньше ресурсов телефона, чтобы он не умер( потому как GPS навигация - дело весьма энергозатратное ). Задействуйте класс Criteria для выбора наиболее подходящего источника, обладающего невысокой точностью и малым потреблением энегрии.

Если выбрать слишком большой интервал обновления координат, можно будет столкнуться с очевидной проблемой неравности модуля перемещения и пройденного пути. Так что, в целом, нужно вам самим разобраться и выбрать наиболее сбалансированный вариант.

Comment: спасибо. согласен с вами. я какой-то средний вариант придумаю и протестирую на своем телефоне. Посмотрю как батарея будет работать. Еще вопрос: можно ли сделать сервис, который будет сам перезапускаться если его убьют вручную?